# slide toggle div code which close when clicked again

Tags: jquery, html

I'm still relatively new to jQuery, I'm using the below code, and it works basically for what I want: to show multiple content in the same container but only have one active at a time and hides the rest.

However I also want to get it so: if you click the same button again for a content that's active, it closes that content again so all content is then hidden. I just can't get it to work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="links" data-showdiv="content1" id="button1">Button 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="links" data-showdiv="content2" id="button2">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="links" data-showdiv="content3" id="button3">Button 3</a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="divs" id="content1" style="display:none">
        Test content 1
    </div>
    <div class="divs" id="content2" style="display:none">
        Test content 2
    </div>
    <div class="divs" id="content3" style="display:none">
        Test content 3
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".links").click(function () {
        $(".divs:visible").slideToggle();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("data-showdiv")).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/Lw519agg/

Comment: Thanks, this works too, just a little off the scenario I wanted it in but would be great for a tabbed content box area :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change your logic to first check if the target div is already visible. Try this:

```
$(".links").click(function () {
    var $target = $("#" + $(this).data('showdiv'));
    if ($target.is(':visible')) {
        $(".divs:visible").slideToggle();
    } else {
        $target.slideDown().siblings().slideUp();
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4o63guz/)

Comment: Thanks this works great :), I was hoping I wasn't far off but it looks like I was a bit off and there was a better way of doing it.